# Not able to pick initialRouteName in Expo Router when using stacked navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-router

I cloned the sample Expo Navigation example project:
https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/templates/expo-template-tabs

Official documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/routing/introduction/

And added another folder with screens:
[image: navigation structure]

[image: navigation definition]

However, the (initial) screens in my structure always get displayed in the app first, no matter what the value of **initialRouteName** is. I tried setting it to (main) but still seeing (initial).
The only way to see (main) is to remove the whole (initial) folder.

Any thoughts on why this is happening or what can I do?

Comment: Please add code instead of adding screenshots. It will help others to reach your post by search.

Answer (score 1):

In your main _layout file:

```js
export const unstable_settings = {
    initialRouteName: "(main)/index",
};
```

Comment: this one works properly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `index` word instead:

```js
export const unstable_settings = {
  initialRouteName: 'index',
};
```

If you take a look at [the docs page](https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/router-settings/) You will see:

> You can specify the name of a group in the `unstable_settings` object to target a particular segment.

So maybe your change would be like this:

```js
export const unstable_settings = {
  // Used for `(foo)`
  initialRouteName: 'first',
  // Used for `(bar)`
  bar: {
    initialRouteName: 'second',
  },
};
```

Comment: But both (initial) and (main) router groups - folders have file named "index". The goal is to either render (initial) when the app loads or (main) group. And Im assuming index file will be rendered first within that group.

Comment: Not quite sure what would be "bar" in my case. And in the documentation it seems to be related to some array syntax which I'm not using.

Comment: And in their official repo they link to a router group https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/templates/expo-template-tabs/app/_layout.tsx#L15 Its just when i create another folder all of sudden there are issues.

Answer (score 0):

@AmerillicA the solution is to have just ONE index file, in your case rename the index to another thing in the initial folder.

Comment: what are you replying to? Amerillica is the most recent _editor_ of the question post- not the asker of the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

An expo engineering manager has said this will not be possible. You can handle redirects manually however. A problem I had in my own project was that the stack replacement animations would not behave as I desired, so I did the equivalent of the following in your example:

in app/layout.tsx:

```
export const unstable_settings = {
  initialRouteName: '(main)',
};
```

And some more info on the problems people are having / Evan bacon commentary:
https://github.com/expo/router/issues/428

Answer (score -2):

Please try to exchange **the lines 57 and 56** and also modify the `(main)` to `(main)/index`.